# IndexError: list index out of range with nested list

Tags: list, python-3.6, nested-lists

```
for i in list404:
    for j in range(len(table)):
        if table[j][0] == i:
            table.remove(table[j])
    for k in range(len(stack)):
        if stack[k][0] == i:
            stack.remove(stack[k])
    for l in range(len(symbols)):
        if symbols[l] == i:
            symbols.remove(symbols[l])
```

list404 is a list of stocks. I'd like to remove the stocks inside the table, stack and symbols with the name shows up in the list404. The table and stack are the nested list I guess. The structure is like this: [[a, b, c], [a, b, c], [a, b, c]]. All I want is to check whether a is in the list404. If it exist, remove the whole list from table.

Here's the error. IndexError: list index out of range in if table[j][0] == i:

Can anyone help me with it??? Thx!

Comment: You're removing elements from `table` in the loop, which means that you no longer have the same number of elements that you got from `len(table)` at the start of the loop. You end up running off the end of the list.

Comment: Oh I see! But how can i solve this problem???

Comment: Stop removing elements from the list. :-) Or iterate backward in the list (from the end to the start) instead, which stops you from running off the end.

Answer (score 0):

as [Ken White](https://stackoverflow.com/users/62576/ken-white) said , you should not remove elements from table in the loop of its length,
i think instead of that you can just make a new list and if the item is valid in your conditions , put it in the new list :

note: as i dont know what the structure of your data exactly looks like , I just write a sample code but you can change it for your data.

```
new_table = []
new_stack = []
new_symbols = []
for i in list404:
    for j in range(len(table)):
        if table[j][0] != i:
            new_table.append(table[j])
    for k in range(len(stack)):
        if stack[k][0] != i:
            new_stack.append(stack[k])
    for l in range(len(symbols)):
        if symbols[l] != i:
            new_symbols.append(symbols[l])
```